# Hive: Shell script to load CSV file into a Hive table?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

My MapReduce job generates a CSV file and stores it in HDFS as:

```
hdfs:///data/input/
```

which generates two files in HDFS:

```
/data/input/SUCCESS
/data/input/part-m-00000
```

How can I load this CSV file in HIVE table in a command line / shell script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS + HCatalog will treat directories as a single file if they contain sequencefiles.

The easiest way to do what you are asking is to simply [create an external table with the LOCATION specified](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) and the location you use will just be the directory, not the path to the whole 0000001(etc) file